# Trackablecollection problem in EF

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, configuration

I newbie in EF.

I have Table A linked together to table B, by passing a primary ID from table A which is a secondary ID on table B Iam trying to retrieve an object from table B.
But I am getting trackableCollection'1[Object name(from table B)]

Any suggestions?
I am trying to retrieve using stored proc
here is the code:

select * from tableB as da
    left outer join tableA as cr on da.ID = cr.ID
    where da.ID = @d

Comment: oh my... how are you trying to retrieve theese objects?

Comment: Sorry about that, I just posted

Comment: I figured it out myself.Actually windows service was giving some inconsequential message and when I changed the exception to stacktrace it showed me actual exception which had nothing to do with EF.And I was thinking the whole time that my EF stored proc is not working for reason.